# Algoritmo para AST

Tags: c++, algoritmo, interpretador

Estou criando uma linguagem de programação no C++. Fiz um lexer simples, que funciona perfeitamente bem por enquanto.

```
out 5 + 7 * 3
```

Meu lexer transforma isso em:

```
kw:  out
num: 5
op:  +
num: 7
op:  *
num: 3
nl
```

Agora preciso criar uma AST (árvore de sintaxe abstrata), que transforme o exemplo em isso:

```
   kw out
      |
    op +
    /  \
num 5  op *
       /  \
   num 7  num 2
```

Mas, como se faz um algoritmo de árvore?

***Nota*** Por favor não postem um código, isso tira toda a graça. Em vez disso, me falem a lógica do algoritmo.

Comment: Embora a sua pergunta não seja duplicata exata dessa outra que linkei, ela é uma duplicata aproximada. Explico: A sua pergunta é diferente, mas as respostas que você precisa estão todas nessa outra pergunta aí (tanto na pergunta em si como nas respostas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples. Você identifica na expressão o último operador a ser operado. Associe a esse operador todos os seus operandos adequadamente, cada um estruturado como expressão. Aí você trata cada uma dessas expressões de operandos da mesma forma que você acabou de fazer, recursivamente. A recursão termina quando a expressão não tiver mais operadores. Se não ficou claro, me avise.

Comment: Claro, isso funciona para operadores, mas e se eu trabalhar com algo assim: `var1 = 15` `var2 = [156, 'txt', var1, [1..5]]`? **PS:** meu lexer identifica textos, então `'txt'` ficará `strl: txt`

Comment: Se ver a atribuição como operador, isso possibilitará simplificações interessantes. Listas também podem ser vistas como operadores de múltiplos operandos, uma operação que bota expressões dentro de uma lista.

Comment: Tipo, o que não é constante nem variável é operação, correto? :D